# Does iPad Mini have a proximity sensor?

Tags: ipad, proximitysensor

I would like my iOS 7 app running on the iPad Mini to detect if there is something close to the proximity sensor (within six inches)

Does iPad Mini have a proximity sensor?

Is it accessible via a API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Mini) for more info.

Additionally, you can enable proximity monitoring on `[UIDevice currentDevice]`, and read its proximity state property.

More info is in the [Apple dev documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/proximityState).

Comment: I am trying this on iPad Mini With Retina.  I can not get the SetProximityMonitoringEnabled to TRUE.


    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isProximityMonitoringEnabled])
    {
        NSLog(@"Proximity Enabled");
    }